# Do I need to worry about setting off my own mines in Far Cry 3?

Tags: far-cry-3

I just got some mines.

I *like* mines.

When I'm tucked into a sniper hide or quietly clearing a long tunnel, there's nothing like knowing there's a couple of mines between me and the bad guys.

The trouble with mining the only way in, though, is that it's my only way out.

**Do I need to worry about setting off my own mines?**

Comment: Didn't want to do the trial and error method ? haha

Comment: @ZeroStack - When I asked the question I was halfway through a difficult mission and I didn't want to blow myself up before finding a save checkpoint.

Comment: That completely makes sense - as I've been there before, but I just thought it was a tad comical :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't trigger your own mines by walking over them. However, when they explode due to an enemy walking over them or you shooting them, you'll take damage from them if you are too close.